# Is there any php code available for rss to email instant notification?

Tags: rss, rss2, email-notifications

I don't want to pay for services like feedmyinbox or something similar. I have a server. So is there any php code available?

I want to be emailed instantly if there is an update found in the feed. So the script does the following.

1. I add the feed url
2. It checks the feed every "x" minutes.
3. If there is an update found it emails me the details.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a script here. Its a nice script. I found this page after 2 hours of googling.

If anyone want [go here and download it](http://ibad.bebasbelanja.com/rss-go-email.html)

Thankyou

PS: I found an error in the code. You need to edit rss-go-email.php and change line 69

from

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rss2email(title,guid,description) VALUES ('$title','$guid','$desc')");
```

to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO rssgoemail(title,guid,description) VALUES ('$title','$guid','$desc')");
```

If you don't change it then it won't work properly.

Comment: That link is dead. Could you please zip it up and share it on your own server please? Thanks mate.

Comment: @SixfootJames I know I'm a little late. My fork of rssgoemail is located here: https://github.com/e-dschungel/rssgoemail